# Unified Inbox in Microsoft Outlook 2010

Tags: vba, outlook

I have two IMAP accounts and one POP account configured in MS Outlook 2010.  Extensive Google research indicates Outlook does not support a truly unified inbox, where these three accounts would be combined, and where the IMAP emails would still be associated with and controlled by their IMAP servers.  Using rules to copy messages disassociates them from IMAP, so that will not work.

Can this be accomplished with VBA's `Application.AdvancedSearch` method?  I'm not fluent in VBA, so if someone could provide an example of a programmatically-created Outlook Search Folder that scans **multiple** email accounts, that would be terrific.

Thank you!

Comment: What you want is not possible within Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work well in Outlook 2010:

See: http://www.slipstick.com/how-to-outlook/how-to-create-a-unified-inbox/

Good luck.